# How to call a method on a generic of a specific type

Tags: java, service, dao

In the below Service I'm trying to init my Dao and inject the EntityManager into it.  We're not using spring for this project.  My IDE is complaining about calling `setEntityManager()` because it can't recognize that the object is always a `GenericDao`.  Is this the proper way to do this?

```
public class GenericService<T, Dao> {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.class.getName());

    protected Dao dao;
    protected EntityManager em;

    public GenericService(Class<Dao> daoClass) {
        try {
            dao = daoClass.newInstance();

            EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("unit");
            em = emf.createEntityManager();

            dao.setEntityManager(em);

        } catch(InstantiationException e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Unable to initialize DAO: {1}", daoClass.getClass());
        } catch(IllegalAccessException e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Unable to initialize DAO: {1}", daoClass.getClass());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a cast:

```
((GenericDao)dao).setEntityManager(em);
```

But I think if you know it's always a GenericDao, why not just make it that type to begin with, e.g.

```
protected GenericDao dao;
```

And change the class declaration as well:

```
public class GenericService<T, GenericDao>
```

Comment: Good call... what I needed was `public class GenericService<T, Dao extends GenericDao> {`